# Codeblocks C 'Hello World' : No such file or directory

Tags: c, codeblocks

I'm having trouble getting CodeBlocks to run any program for me in Mac OS Terminal, it says it can't find the file. This is my first attempt at programming.

Haven't found any answers for this on Youtube or Stackoverflow...

This is the build log, not sure how to format the code so it fits neatly in a non-scrolling box...

```
-------------- Run: Release in Giraffe (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler)---------------

Checking for existence: /Users/eyobsharew/Desktop/projects/coding projects/Giraffe/bin/Release/Giraffe
Executing: osascript -e 'tell app "Terminal"' -e 'activate' -e 'do script "/private/var/folders/g6/mh3pr_nd49zfdtrtbn4glc080000gn/T/AppTranslocation/F3C8275A-DA19-42A9-A6DA-CB218BF5C51B/d/CodeBlocks.app/Contents/MacOS/cb_console_runner DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=$DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH:. /Users/eyobsharew/Desktop/projects/coding\ projects/Giraffe/bin/Release/Giraffe "' -e 'end tell'  (in /Users/eyobsharew/Desktop/projects/coding projects/Giraffe/.)
Process terminated with status 0 (0 minute(s), 3 second(s))
```

Comment: what is the code?

Comment: There is a stray backslash that looks suspicious and out of place on a unix-style filesystem: `/Users/eyobsharew/Desktop/projects/coding\\`  You might look through your project files and see if that's been entered in some form slot somewhere and change it to a forward slash or delete it.

Comment: @HostileFork that one looks like a folder name that includes a space.

Comment: it worked! the folder name was changed to 'coding projects' in Finder which didn't correspond to what CodeBlocks was looking for. Would there be a way to update which folder the file CodeBlocks was looking for to prevent this in the future?